# .NET 4.0 System.Data issue

Tags: .net, entity-framework, 64-bit, system.data

I am developing a .NET 4.0 application. It runs fine on the development machine (win7 32bit), but it reports this issue when installed and started on a win7 64bit machine.

I think the issue has something to do with the System.Data module, because the very first thing the application does is to access database. I use the Entity Framework.

Would you please help? or at least give me a hint or a similar experience?

[image: Application halts and this error box appears]

Comment: Of course, I did build a 64bit compatible version.

Comment: Check windows event logs, you can find more info about your problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You should, IMO, either run the application on the target machine under a debugger (such as WinDbg), or take a crash-dump and analyze it (right-click the process in Task Manager, choose "Create Dump File"). This would allow you to know what is really happening, rather than guessing.

Comment: Thank you! There was an error with the database. It should normally be created automatically with initial tables. But somehow the tables were not. I installed VS on another 64bit machine and debugged.